# anova like object for betaregression

Tags: r, anova

I'm wondering, is there any anova-like object in R for betaregression? I know it is not implemented in `betareg` package but I don't see why is that.

If there is no such an object, is there any easy was how to perform it?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

What I actually want is to determine significance of factors. With `lmtest` package it would be something like that:

```
library("betareg")
data("ReadingSkills", package = "betareg")

m1 <- betareg(accuracy ~ dyslexia, data = ReadingSkills)
m2 <- betareg(accuracy ~ iq, data = ReadingSkills)
m3 <- betareg(accuracy ~ iq + dyslexia, data = ReadingSkills)
library("lmtest")
lrtest(m2, m3)
lrtest(m1, m3)
```

But with a large number of covariates in the model this approach seems to be a little bit uncomfortable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297465/deviance-in-hurdle-model/299857#299857 beta regression models are not standard GLMs, especially if they have regressors in the precision submodel. Therefore, an analysis of deviance does not work in the same way as in GLMs. (Consequently, the proposed `Anova()` solution from @Adela is incorrect.)

Instead one can use the generic `waldtest()` and `lrtest()` functions from package `lmtest` to carry out Wald or likelihood ratio tests for nested model comparisons. This is also illustrated in `vignette("betareg", package = "betareg")` and a simple example is also included below:

```
library("betareg")
data("ReadingSkills", package = "betareg")
m0 <- betareg(accuracy ~ 1 | 1, data = ReadingSkills)
m1 <- betareg(accuracy ~ iq | 1, data = ReadingSkills)
m2 <- betareg(accuracy ~ iq + dyslexia | 1, data = ReadingSkills)
m3 <- betareg(accuracy ~ iq + dyslexia | iq + dyslexia, data = ReadingSkills)
library("lmtest")
lrtest(m0, m1, m2, m3)
## Likelihood ratio test
## 
## Model 1: accuracy ~ 1 | 1
## Model 2: accuracy ~ iq | 1
## Model 3: accuracy ~ iq + dyslexia | 1
## Model 4: accuracy ~ iq + dyslexia | iq + dyslexia
##   #Df LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
## 1   2 26.421                         
## 2   3 34.586  1 16.330  5.322e-05 ***
## 3   4 49.951  1 30.730  2.966e-08 ***
## 4   6 61.257  2 22.612  1.230e-05 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the new point of view on this topic. So I guess there is no way how to "automatically" determine significance of covariates in betaregression models..

Comment: I wouldn't know what exactly you _conceptually_ want to do to automatically determine significance of all covariates. If you do, it shouldn't be hard _computationally_. In other words: I don't think this is a software issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found the answer - it is possible with `Anova()` function from `car` package.